# Large amount of projected I/O with Oracle, even if only a single record is fetched

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I often encounter the following situation in my Oracle execution plans:

```
Operation                   | Object  | Order | Rows | Bytes | Projection
----------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------+-------------
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PROD    |     7 |   2M |   28M | PROD.VALUE
  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PROD_PK |     6 |   1  |       | PROD.ROWID
```

This is an extract from a larger execution plan. Essentially, I'm accessing (joining) a table using the table's primary key. Typically, there is another table `ACCO` with `ACCO.PROD_ID = PROD.ID`, where `PROD_PK` is the primary key on `PROD.ID`. Obviously, the table can be accessed using a `UNIQUE SCAN`, but as soon as I have some silly projection on that table, it seems as though the whole table (around 2 million rows) is planned to be read in memory. I get a lot of I/O and buffer gets. When I remove the projection from the greater query, the problem disappears:

```
Operation                   | Object  | Order | Rows | Bytes | Projection
----------------------------+---------+-------+------+-------+-------------
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | PROD    |     7 |   1  |     8 | PROD.ID
  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PROD_PK |     6 |   1  |       | PROD.ROWID
```

I don't understand this behaviour. What could be the reasons for this? Note, I cannot post the complete query. It is rather complex and involves a lot of calculations. The pattern, however, is often the same.

**UPDATE**: I maganged to bring down my rather complex setup to a simple simulation that produces a similar execution plan in both cases (when projecting `PROD.VALUE` or when leaving it away):

#### Create the following database:

```
-- products have a value
create table prod as
select level as id, 10 as value from dual 
connect by level < 100000;
alter table prod add constraint prod_pk primary key (id);

-- some products are accounts
create table acco as
select level as id, level as prod_id from dual 
connect by level < 50000;
alter table acco 
  add constraint acco_pk primary key (id);
alter table acco 
  add constraint acco_prod_fk foreign key (prod_id) references prod (id);

-- accounts have transactions with values
create table trxs as
select level as id, mod(level, 10) + 1 as acco_id, mod(level, 17) + 1 as value
from dual connect by level < 100000;
alter table trxs 
  add constraint trxs_pk primary key (id);
alter table trxs 
  add constraint trxs_acco_fk foreign key (acco_id) references acco (id);

create index acco_i on acco(prod_id);
create index trxs_i on trxs(acco_id);

alter table acco modify prod_id not null;
alter table trxs modify acco_id not null;
```

#### Run the following query

```
select v2.*
from (
  select 
    -- This calculates the balance for every transaction as a
    -- running total, subtracting trxs.value from the product's value
    --
    -- This is the "projection" I mentioned that causes I/O. Leaving it
    -- away (setting it to 0), would improve the execution plan
    prod.value - v1.total balance,
    acco.id acco_id
  from (
    select 
      acco_id,
      sum(value) over (partition by acco_id
                       order by id
                       rows between unbounded preceding 
                       and current row) total
    from trxs
  ) v1
  join acco on v1.acco_id = acco.id
  join prod on acco.prod_id = prod.id
) v2
-- This is the single-row access predicate. From here, it is
-- clear that there can only be 1 acco and 1 prod
where v2.acco_id = 1;
```

#### Analyse

When analysing execution plans for the above query (with or without any `prod.value` projection), I can reproduce an excessive amount of rows / bytes in the plan when accessing the `prod` table.

I have found a [workaround for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681134/521799). But I'm really interested in an explanation about what is going wrong and how I could correct this problem without changing the query too much

### Update

OK, after much more analysis, I have to say that the actual problematic I/O was due to a wrong index being used somewhere entirely else. Unfortunately, this was not well-enough projected in overall statistics (or in the execution plan) to notice.

As far as this question goes, I'm still curious about the projected I/O in the execution plan, as that appears to confuse our DBA (and me) time and again. And sometimes, it really *is* the source of I/O problems...

Comment: I think we need to look at the query to help... Could you simplify it, make sure it still behaves as you described it, and post it here?

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz: I'll wait until someone has a more concrete hint for me to look for (they usually do). Reducing the problem to something that I can post here is non-trivial...

Comment: @LukasEder hey, what do u mean "it seems as though the whole table is planned to be read in memory"?  U mean a FTS?  Also, not sure your meaning of "remove the projection from the greater query".

Comment: @LukasEder - What sort of calculations are you talking about?  Are there aggregations that need to read the data from all 2 million rows in the table in order to return the computed value?  The query plan you posted implies that there is no filter condition.  If the query is only returning one row, that implies that you're doing a lot of aggregation.

Comment: @tbone: I actually don't understand why having a projection like `TAB.SOME_COL` causes this much I/O (`Rows: 2M, Bytes: 28M`) in the execution plan, when it is well-known from the index access, that there can only be 1 row. When removing the `TAB.SOME_COL` projection (replacing it by a `1` literal for instance), the plan turns out as expected. There is no FTS, but the estimates seem to be really off even if statistics are OK. Although, maybe there is a misunderstanding on my part, hence the question

Comment: @JustinCave: It's non-trivial to simplify that query as it contains a lot of nested views. I'll try to post something tomorrow. The calculations I'm doing are a running total subtracted from that particular projection... Anyway, the query returns many rows, but the join only returns one row. The projection is not part of any aggregation. It could be accessed once in the whole query by Oracle. I feel that this is a very general problem, so I'm actually not sure if the concrete query matters here...

Comment: @LukasEder any way you can post a simple query example joining TAB with XXX (populate sample data with all_objects maybe)?  This would answer a lot of questions I think. (oh, just saw your response to Justin, same question he had I suppose)

Comment: @LukasEder - As the answer is dependant on what processing is being done on the data, and the query is non-trivial, I'd have to say that the answer is going to be non-trivial.  If you want to understand the general case, can you replicate the general case with a generic data structure and query?  If you want an answer to your specific case, we need to know about your specific case.

Comment: @LukasEder - Also, can you clarify whether the problem is actual measured I/O (i.e. from tracing the session) or projected I/O from the query plan?  It sounds like you're saying that both are problems but that's not 100% clear to me.

Comment: @tbone: I have added an example, replacing `TAB` and `XXX` with some more meaningful names

Comment: @Dems: I have added an example for this specific case. I guess, from the specific case, we'll be able to conclude a general rule...

Comment: @JustinCave: I can only measure lots of I/O under heavy load. I suspect that the projected I/O indicates that there is a problem, but I'm not sure. Note, I have added an example

Comment: @LukasEder: Forgive me a paranoid question; have the optimizer statistics been updated at a time representative of the table content?

Comment: @JirkaHanika: Yes, they have. Statistics do not seem to influence this issue...

Comment: The key question is if the  predicate v2.acco_id = 1 is pushed into the query of the trxs table. The only way to figure this out is dumping the optimizer statistics.

Comment: @steve: Or, by analysing other parts of the plan. And indeed it is pushed down into the trxs table. That part is handled optimally

Comment: @LukasEder: Could you please post the query plan with and without "projection"? Looks like IO is coming from txns table, and if you comment out usage of v1.value, Oracle proves that join to txns is not required and just eliminates that join.

Comment: @VladimirSitnikov: As I mentioned in the question update, the actual I/O is indeed coming from a bad index choice where the `trxs` table is joined (again). This is not reflected in my example, though. So the question that remains is not related to the actual I/O problem, but to the bad projected I/O as shown in the question, which is actually not a real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be interesting to note that I have checked up on various scenarios, including a *specific* solution for the *specific* example. Re-phrase the sample query to be like this would solve the problem in *this case*:

```
select
  -- Explicitly project value in a nested loop. This seems to be much cheaper
  -- in this specific case
  (select value from prod where id = v2.prod_id) - v2.balance,
  v2.acco_id
from (
  select 
    -- Now, balance is only a running total, not the running total
    -- added to PROD.VALUE
    v1.total balance,
    acco.id acco_id,
    acco.prod_id prod_id
  from (
    select 
      acco_id,
      sum(value) over (partition by acco_id
                       order by id
                       rows between unbounded preceding 
                       and current row) total
    from trxs
  ) v1
  -- The JOIN of PROD is no longer needed
  join acco on v1.acco_id = acco.id
) v2
where v2.acco_id = 1;
```

But I still don't understand why Oracle would project so much I/O in its execution plan, if I join `prod` earlier in this query...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when selecting v1.total, you're triggering a no_merge view.

When using analytics function in sub-selects, the sub-selects need to be resolved before joining with the rest, so, in this case v1 is executed fully and the entire resultset is "fetched", before it is joined. And looking at you query, that means full scan on trxs+ a sort for the analytic function

When commenting out v1.total, then the optimizer merges the view and ignores the function entirely, as it sees that it is not used.

**Update**

I used your sample, here is the [fiddle for your original query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9319a/1), and for [your solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9319a/3). Explain plans statistics differ in the "unique scan of Prod". Explain plan have no way of accurately estimating the cost of queries in the select clause, it does show how it will be executed when a row is fetched, but it doesn't tell how many times it will be executed, and it doesn't cost it. The cost you see there, is only the cost to fetch the 1st row, but the query will run every time you fetch a row, and the execution plan has no idea how many you will fetch. That should explain the cost and IO prediction differences.

On a side note, Queries in the Select clause, do not scale, unless you're sure that the over query will return a finite, predictable, and a manageable number of rows, avoid using them. They will come and bite you later:)

y

Comment: I'm not commenting out `v1.total`. Maybe that's a bit confusing in my example because it is renamed from `v1.total` to `v2.balance`... Effectively, there is no need for a full scan on `trxs` either, as indexes can be used for the analytic function's `partition by`, `order by` and `windowing clause`...

Comment: Please post which 2 queries you're comparing.

Comment: I've posted the original query in the question, and a possible workaround in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9681134/521799)...